# How do I renew my Developer Program Account?

Tags: developer-program

How do I renew my Developer Program Account. The Account I used to have has expired. Please give very clear and specific instructions.

Answer (score 4):

*Links updated Nov 2016*

According to Apple, you can renew your membership anytime after it expires by signing in to [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/) with the Apple ID you used to enroll in the iOS Developer Program.

Following that link, after login, you will see an screen with renew options.

[image]

Source: [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/)

Comment: I need clearer instructions than what Apple is providing. The only "renew options" that I can see in the Member center end up with me being told "you cannot create this account because it already exists". I need clearer instructions to make sure I am doing the right thing - simply saying "go to the Member Center" is not enough.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you follow the link provided, just after the login, you must see renewal options like in the image above.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I cannot find this. I need a very specific, step by step break down to lead me here.

Comment: Did you login through this link -> [https://developer.apple.com/ios/renew/index.action](https://developer.apple.com/ios/renew/index.action)? If after login through it won't see the renew options, better contact with [Apple Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).

Comment: This link gives me the message: "We are unable to process your request. An unknown error occurred. Please try again." Unfortunately I came here after a very unhelpful session with Apply Support, they wouldn't do anymore than tell me to "Follow the link in the Member Center", and after telling them that this wasn't helping me they refused to reply to me any further. Never had this many difficulties in giving a company money before.